# android -Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_armv7DebugApkCopy'

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, crosswalk

Since few days I have this problem

Before, compile was ok, but now I always have this error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_armv7DebugApkCopy'.
  >   Could not find com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.1.0.
  >    Required by:
  >        :android:unspecified > org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:23.53.589.4 > com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0
  >   Could not find com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0.
  >    Required by:
  >        :android:unspecified > org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:23.53.589.4 > com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0
  >   Could not find com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0.
  >    Required by:
  >        :android:unspecified > org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:23.53.589.4 > com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0 > com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0
  >        :android:unspecified > org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:23.53.589.4 > com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0 > com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0
  >        :android:unspecified > org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:23.53.589.4 > com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0 > com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0
  >   Could not find android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.0.0.
  >    Required by:
  >        :android:unspecified > org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:23.53.589.4 > com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0 > com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0 > android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.0

I'm Using Cordova@6.4.0
Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

in the android gradle file you need to specify the following

```
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
```

and then find this text " compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7"
and make sure it says
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1"

Also make sure that your other build.gradle file add maven url 'https://maven.google' should look like this

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I have new error AAPT: No resource identifier found for attribute 'appComponentFactory' in package 'android'

Comment: try Enzo BLANCHON solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I thinks it's a knowned cordova problem when using multiple plugins that use multiple versions of gradle.

You can handle this with this plugin : https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-support-gradle-release

You maybe should remove the TrooperMaXX solution before try this.